# Cannot create Bean after @Autowired EurekaDiscoveryClient

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to create bean cassandraServer which uses IP address fetched from Netflix Eureka server, but everytime it throws NPE for discoveryClient.

How can I create Bean using properties from Eureka Server?

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @Bean
    public String cassandraServer() throws InterruptedException {
        return this.discoveryClient.getInstances("some-service").get(0).getHost();
    }
}

@RestController
class ServiceInstanceRestController {

    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @RequestMapping("/service-instances/{applicationName}")
    public List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstancesByApplicationName(@PathVariable String applicationName) {
        return this.discoveryClient.getInstances(applicationName);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using EurekaClient instead of DiscoveryClient?

Comment: thanks for the reply. it was just a version error, it automatically got fixed when i changed spring cloud eureka discovery version.